# jquery select and use part of class name

Tags: jquery, class, strip

I have a lot of classes who starts with `edit_`. I've styled them with `[class^="edit_"]`. Now, each class have a different number like `edit_20` `edit_80` `edit_150`. How can i strip the first part of the class name (`edit_`) so that if passing it to a variable, it will only contain the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `.split()` it out with `_` and get the second element from the returned array.,

```
var number = "edit_20".split('_')[1];
```

Comment: Thanks. It works if there's just 1 class assigned to that element. In some elements i have more than 1 class. In this case: `<span class="edit_80 uppercase word_break">` with this: `$(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];` the console.log gives me this: `80 uppercase word`...is there something i miss? Isn't the `[1]` filtering the second element already?

Comment: @Mariano Then get the first element from the array. and split it..!

Comment: ok...the function itself works...but why if used this way it doesn't work anymore: [link](http://pastebin.com/d7AFJGcV)?
if returning manually a number, it works (example `return 2;`)

Comment: @Mariano in my office pastebin got blocked.. can you show the demo in fiddle.?

Comment: it won't work in fiddle as i should load external files, but i use it anyway to paste the code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/s9d7r/)

Comment: @Mariano Then do one thing, ask that as a newer question with the pastebin link included in that, so that it would get more expert's eye on that..

Comment: Hi, i got no reply from the other thread...i've some more clues: checking the html generated, i find `maxlength="[object Object]"` value...any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Simple replace can do but make sure to convert into int.

```
 var number = parseInt(str.replace("edit_",''));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with Regex:

```
 if(/^edit_(\d*)/.test('edit_20'))
      var num = (/^edit_(\d*)/.exec('edit_20'))[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, for those who will be landing here...i solved this way:

```
$("[class^='edit_']").each( function() {
    var ml = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].split('_')[1];
    $(this).editable('[url]', {
        [...]
        maxlength   : ml,
    });
});
```