# jeditable dynamic maxlength

Tags: jquery, jeditable, maxlength

following up to this question: [jquery select and use part of class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242938/jquery-select-and-use-part-of-class-name)

i thought to use this way to dynamically assign a maxlength to the jeditable script (i assign a special class to each element startig with `edit_*`, where the star is the maxlength):

```
$("[class^='edit_']").editable('url', {
    id          : $(this).attr('id'),
    maxlength   : $("[class^='edit_']").on('click',function() {
            return $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].split('_')[1];
    }),
});
```

problem is that while the function itself works if used separately, it doesn't work inside the above script. I even tried to return a number manually (ex. `return 2`) and it works...what's the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, for those who will be landing here...i solved this way:

```
$("[class^='edit_']").each( function() {
    var ml = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].split('_')[1];
    $(this).editable('[url]', {
        [...]
        maxlength   : ml,
    });
});
```